# Need a good mp3/internet radio organization system

Tags: streaming, mp3, music-management

So I feel that winamp alone doesn't work well for me. I have this one playlist that all kinds of stuff gets crammed into. I need a system (this can easily be 1 program or several):

Need to be able to...

- play mp3's from my library (just a directory structure with mp3's).
- Save radio station's, and easily remove/add new stations
- play random mp3's which are not part of my library and will probably be deleted in the future, yet won't clutter my library index!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I have done:

1. Using [Winamp](http://www.winamp.com/) for radio stations (Winamp has the [best](http://www.winamp.com/plugin/enhancer-017/81361) DSP plugins, which really helps here)
2. Using [Songbird](http://www.getsongbird.com/) as a library (awsome library, I rank so much of my MP3s, it helps me delete stuff that I no longer want to listen to again.... as I get tired of skipping it everytime it comes up in my mp3/player or PS3).
3. Using [AIMP](http://www.aimp2.us/aimpl.php) (as recommended by UK) to play newly downloaded MP3's which haven't made it to the library yet (as they might not depending on if I like them enough).

This is done more effeciently now as I am not having playlists interfere with my stations and vice versa.

Answer (score 11):

[foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/)

- Supported audio formats: MP3, MP4, AAC, CD Audio, WMA, Vorbis, FLAC, WavPack, WAV, AIFF, Musepack, Speex, AU, SND... and more with additional components.
- Gapless playback.
- Full unicode support.
- Easily customizable user interface layout.
- Advanced tagging capabilities.
- Support for ripping Audio CDs as well as transcoding all supported audio formats using the Converter component.
- Full ReplayGain support.
- Customizable keyboard shortcuts.
- Open component architecture allowing third-party developers to extend functionality of the player.

[image]
(out of the box screenshot, for an overview of the possibilities: http://images.google.com/images?q=foobar)

> - play mp3's from my library (just a directory structure with mp3's).

fb2k has a media library that you can query with the [title formatting syntax](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=Foobar2000:Titleformat_Reference) to create auto organized playlist and "library views" (trees or multi-columns with artist, album, genre, date, encoding, ...). And of course you can use your directory structure

> - Save radio station's, and easily remove/add new stations

By default fb2k support HTTP, ASX, MMS and RTSP streams. And you can add [foo_lastfm_radio](http://www.unkempt.co.uk/fb2k/foo_lastfm_radio.html) for last.fm radios and [foo_podcatcher](http://www.unkempt.co.uk/fb2k/foo_podcatcher.html) for podcasts

> - play random mp3's which are not part of my library and will probably be deleted in the future, yet won't clutter my library index!

If the mp3 added to fb2k aren't in the media library path(s) they aren't added to the library.
So you can use an "incoming" playlist for the new tracks, and if you want to keep them, use title formatting to send the files to your directory structure according to theirs ID3 tags (and so indexing them)

fb2k is easily the best audio player/manager for power user. Out of the box it does the essential better than any other and the component architecture with the dedicated community do the rest...

Update, some resources to climb the learning curve:

- [from winamp to foobar](http://winamp2foobar.blogspot.com/)
- [wiki](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=Foobar2000:Foobar2000)
- [forum](http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/index.php?showforum=28)

Comment: sounds good so far. would be +2 if I could for Tool.

Comment: It's an official screenshot, so give the additional +1 to the dev ;)

Answer (score 1):

Have you come across [Last.fm](http://www.last.fm)?

- Play mp3's from my library. Yes, once you've scrobbled your library.
- Save radio stations, and easily remove/add new stations. Yes, but only stations provided by last.fm
- Play random mp3's which are not part of my library. Yes, if the artist has provided them free. Even suggested to you based on your library.
- ...yet won't clutter my library index! ...Not really. Last.fm doesn't distinguish your scrobbled music from music you have listened too, I think.

Comment: Well now this is interesting...

Answer (score 1):

Try [Boxee](http://www.boxee.tv/).

I wrote an article on this not to long ago: 
http://danielk.org/blog/2010/01/31/great-online-experience/

Answer (score 1):

How about [AIMP](http://www.aimp2.us/) ?

- Work with multiple playlists at once
- Online radio
- Listen and save!

Comment: Thanks for AIMP, never knew about it + I think it is better than winamp at this point, and I have been using winamp for like 11-12 years

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be you differentiate between organizing your offline files (mp3, ...) and internet radio.

For the offline part you already got plenty of recommendations.
For the internet radio I can only say ... [Screamer Radio](http://www.screamer-radio.com/) ... freeware, it has pretty much you'll ever need in that segment. I can't recomment it enough.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [di.fm](http://di.fm)

- A lot of radio stations
- A lot of variety
- Can play on Winamp, WMP and other players.
- Can buy a membership.
- FREE!

Comment: I love di.fm. But I need a way of organizing all my stations and mp3's.

Comment: I misread. Sorry. I sent this post before I finished to read your post. I do love DI.FM too!

Answer (score 0):

[Media Monkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com) can do all this:

- play mp3's from my library (just a directory structure with mp3's).

Yes - it's library management functions are good. Just tell it which folder(s) you want and set it off. Adds all the music files and you can rescan portions of it whenever you need.

- Save radio station's, and easily remove/add new stations

Yes - but I can't find the details on the website.

- play random mp3's which are not part of my library and will probably be deleted in the future, yet won't clutter my library index!

Yes - either just browse to the file using Media Monkey's file explorer or just double click the mp3 (assuming you have Media Monkey set up as the default player).